# How to configure routing table and use await client.GetAsync

Tags: c#, api, web-services, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have a method that call web API that is hosted in a different server by ID, name and password.
My code is pretty standard as following:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    //[Route("api/GetMember/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Member>> GetMember(int id)
    string Baseurl = "https://localhost:5001/";

        string name = "something";
        string password = "somethingelse";
        id = 12121210;


        Member member = new Member();
        member.Name = name;
        member.Password = password;
        member.ID = id;


        string uri = Baseurl + id  + name + "/" + password;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("/api/member/something/somethingelse/12122110");

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var MemResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                member = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Member>(MemResponse);

            }

            return Ok(member);
        }
    }
```

The above works with no problem and returns a JSON string. However when I replace the following line

```
 HttpResponseMessage Res = await 
 client.GetAsync("/api/member/something/somethingelse/12122110");
```

with the follwoing

```
  string uri = Baseurl + id  + name + "/" + password;    
   HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

I get the following

```
 {StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: 
  System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers: { 
  Cache-Control: private Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8? 
  B?SDpcQVRQLkZPX1NDX0NHSVxBVFBGT1NlcnZpY2U=?= X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: 
  Thu, 14 Feb 2019 16:49:04 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
  Content-Length: 5390 }}
```

What am I doing wrong? this is my first web API application and I'm not sure I fully understand the rules.

Comment: `hosted in a different server by ID, name and password` I sure hope that server rejects unencrypted requests!

Comment: So what you saying is that my code is correct, and the request is refused because that my user name and password are not encrypted?

Comment: No; I was just making an observation that the server is doing its own unique kind of security that is unlike anything else, which experience has shown is usually a bad idea.

Comment: But do you have any idea of what it goes wrong with the code?

Comment: Nope. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the issue. It was the parameter of the method which is an int.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Member>> GetMember(int id)
```

changed it to

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Member>> GetMember(string id)
```

Everything worked as it should now.